# C++20 behaviour breaking existing code with equality operator?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, spaceship-operator

I ran into this while debugging [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65638680/using-boost-strong-typedef-to-differentiate-arg-types-but-causing-seg-fault/65643014?noredirect=1#comment116069484_65643014).

I trimmed it down all the way to just using [Boost Operators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/utility/operators.htm):

1. **Compiler Explorer [C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/q89brM) [C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/szYx9E)**

   ```
   #include <boost/operators.hpp>

   struct F : boost::totally_ordered1<F, boost::totally_ordered2<F, int>> {
       /*implicit*/ F(int t_) : t(t_) {}
       bool operator==(F const& o) const { return t == o.t; }
       bool operator< (F const& o) const { return t <  o.t; }
     private: int t;
   };

   int main() {
       #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused"
       F { 42 } == F{ 42 }; // OKAY
       42 == F{42};         // C++17 OK, C++20 infinite recursion
       F { 42 } == 42;      // C++17 OK, C++20 infinite recursion
   }
   ```

   This program compiles and runs fine with C++17 (ubsan/asan enabled) in both GCC and Clang.
2. When you change the *implicit* constructor to `explicit`, the problematic lines obviously **[no longer compile on C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/hq4fve)**

Surprisingly both versions **compile on C++20 ([v1](https://godbolt.org/z/onMzo5) and [v2](https://godbolt.org/z/b1Pav5))**, but they lead to **infinite recursion** (crash or tight loop, depending on optimization level) on the two lines that wouldn't compile on C++17.

Obviously this kind of silent bug creeping in by upgrading to C++20 is worrisome.

Questions:

- Is this c++20 behaviour conformant (I expect so)
- What exactly is interfering? I suspect it might be due to c++20's new "spaceship operator" support, but don't understand **how** it changes the behaviour of this code.

Comment: I believe this is [boost::equality_comparable2 operator== can compile into infinite loop with clang10 and -std=c++2a](https://github.com/boostorg/utility/issues/65)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You guys are seriously fast. The world does not deserve this level of support. Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, but it's definitely related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130311

Comment: @cigien Appreciated. The explanations in the answers there are excellent and help forming a more complete understanding.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Indeed, C++20 unfortunately makes this code infinitely recursive.

Here's a reduced example:

```cpp
struct F {
    /*implicit*/ F(int t_) : t(t_) {}

    // member: #1
    bool operator==(F const& o) const { return t == o.t; }

    // non-member: #2
    friend bool operator==(const int& y, const F& x) { return x == y; }

private:
    int t;
};
```

Let's just look at `42 == F{42}`.

In C++17, we only had one candidate: the non-member candidate (`#2`), so we select that. Its body, `x == y`, itself only has one candidate: the member candidate (`#1`) which involves implicitly converting `y` into an `F`. And then that member candidate compares the two integer members and this is totally fine.

In C++20, the initial expression `42 == F{42}` now has *two* candidates: both the non-member candidate (`#2`) as before and now also the reversed member candidate (`#1` reversed). `#2` is the better match - we exactly match both arguments instead of invoking a conversion, so it's selected.

Now, however, `x == y` now has *two* candidates: the member candidate again (`#1`), but also the reversed non-member candidate (`#2` reversed). `#2` is the better match again for the same reason that it was a better match before: no conversions necessary. So we evaluate `y == x` instead. Infinite recursion.

Non-reversed candidates are preferred to reversed candidates, but only as a tiebreaker. Better conversion sequence is always first.

---

Okay great, how can we fix it? The simplest option is removing the non-member candidate entirely:

```cpp
struct F {
    /*implicit*/ F(int t_) : t(t_) {}

    bool operator==(F const& o) const { return t == o.t; }

private:
    int t;
};
```

`42 == F{42}` here evaluates as `F{42}.operator==(42)`, which works fine.

If we want to keep the non-member candidate, we can add its reversed candidate explicitly:

```cpp
struct F {
    /*implicit*/ F(int t_) : t(t_) {}
    bool operator==(F const& o) const { return t == o.t; }
    bool operator==(int i) const { return t == i; }
    friend bool operator==(const int& y, const F& x) { return x == y; }

private:
    int t;
};
```

This makes `42 == F{42}` still choose the non-member candidate, but now `x == y` in the body there will prefer the member candidate, which then does the normal equality.

This last version can also remove the non-member candidate. The following also works without recursion for all test cases (and is how I would write comparisons in C++20 going forward):

```cpp
struct F {
    /*implicit*/ F(int t_) : t(t_) {}
    bool operator==(F const& o) const { return t == o.t; }
    bool operator==(int i) const { return t == i; }

private:
    int t;
};
```

Comment: Excellent walk through. I'm a bit torn on how to judge the situation. As a professional, I'm really unhappy to see C++ introducing compatibility death traps. I'm happy to see [this sentiment](https://github.com/boostorg/utility/issues/65#issuecomment-636073901) but I fear it looks like nothing much is going to come of it. So libraries just silently break - **at runtime** - which is not a good storyline. I know I've written code that will suffer these issues, and I shudder to think what happens if the current devs upgrade. They'll probably be cursing my code in righteous indignation ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @sehe I'm really unhappy about it too, and it's my fault even. And this specific case is the worst case - the only language change that preserves the C++17 behavior is not having any part of the feature (or having the `==` functionality opt-in, which nobody has come up with a passable way of doing so). Not only is it the only one we can't really fix, but all the other breakages are code that ceases to compile while this one insidiously continues to compile. Just all sorts of bad.

Comment: @sehe And this case even, you could just rewrite the body of `F` to have `auto operator<=>(F const&) const = default;` and that one line gives you all the comparisons. Which is good for C++20 going forward, but not so good for the transitional step obviously.

Comment: I guess I could have a static inspection that just spots `operator==` implementations and have them routinely conditionally replaced with spaceships in c++20 mode... I do feel the future is a lot better. However, it's a landmine waiting to trip people up.

Comment: @Barry I feel like this shouldn't be hard for compilers to statically diagnose (after all, it all happens at compile time). I.e. something like "c++20 compat warning: different overload will be selected depending on the std mode, proposed fix: ...".

Comment: @Dan I'm not a compiler guy, but if you want to take a crack at adding such a warning to clang, I'm sure many people would be very appreciative.